# iOS10 UNNotificationRequest set identifier is @"", device crash and restart constantly

Tags: ios10

My code like this :

```
UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
content.badge = @1;
content.body = @"body";
content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
content.subtitle = @"subtitle";
content.title = @"title";
NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
components.year = 2016;
components.month = 10;
components.day = 26;
components.hour = 10;
components.minute = 35;
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components repeats:YES];
UNNotificationRequest * request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"" content:content trigger:trigger];
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {}];
```

I made a mistake，[UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"" content:content trigger:trigger];set identifier with @"", and run on my device.
And then my device crash and restart again and again.As in the above case, I try to run it on simulator, simulator restart again and again until I reset content and settings.

Now my device can't connect to computer, because it restart again and again and I can't unlock it. So I can't uninstall the error app and reset it. How can this problem be solved?

Comment: instead of empty identifier give some value and try

Comment: Have te same issue. Nothing works :(

Comment: @Joker-388 I am unable to run my phone. It's hanging on apple logo screen after reboot. Have you encounter this issue?